Bounding difference of expectations with a difference of Fourier transforms
Let us define a norm on the vector space of finite signed measures on $\mathbb{R}$ as $\lVert \mu \rVert^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |\hat{\mu}(y)|^2 e^{-y^2} dy,$ where $\hat{\mu}(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-ixy}\mu(dx)$ is the Fourier transform of measure $\mu$. Does there exist a $C>0$, such that for any probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ we have
$$
\left\lvert \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, \mu(dx) - \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \,\nu(dx)\right\rvert \leq C \,\lVert \mu-\nu \rVert? 
$$
I know this bound holds if one uses Wasserstein distance on probability distributions. What about with a norm defined as above? It's easy to show that there exists $D>0$ such that $\lVert \mathbb{\mu - \nu}\rVert \leq D \, W_2(\mu,\nu)$, but this doesn't directly help me with what I want to prove. All help will be appreciated greatly.

Why is $|\mu|$ finite? What type of measures are you considering?

I consider finite signed measures that form a vector space. If I'm not mistaken their fourier transform is bounded and continuous, which should mean that the integral in the definition of the norm exists. I edited the question. The measures I actually consider are all probability measures but I don't think this should matter.

I doubt of the existence of such a $C$. Here is my argument. Let $X$ and $Y$ be rv with respective distributions $\mu$ and $\nu.$ If $Z\sim N(0,1)$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$, denote by $f$ and $g$ the respective densities of $X+Z$ and $Y+Z$. Forgetting the usual multiplicative constants with your definition of the norm we have $\|\mu-\nu\|^2=\int_R(f-g)^2dx$ by the Plancherel theorem. Therefore you are asking for a $C$ such that
$$\left|\int_R x(f(x)-g(x))dx\right|\leq C\left(\int
_R(f-g)^2dx\right)^{1/2}.$$ Well even if $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are less than 1 for instance, the distributions of $X+Z$ and $Y+Z$ are unbounded and the Schwarz inequality seems not applicable without further constraints.
Edit. Actually the impossibility of existence of $C$ can be proved easily by considering the particular case $X=a>0$ and $Y=-a$, meaning $\mu=\delta_a$ and $\nu=
\delta_{-a}.$ A careful calculation leads to
$$2a\leq C\times \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}(1-e^{-a^2})$$ which cannot hold for all $a$ (take $a$ big). I hope that my calculation is correct.

So, if I understand correctly, what you mean in the last paragraph is that if the identity function was in $L^2$, we would have the desired bound. And since the identity function is far from being in $L^2$, you suspect such $C$ doesn't exist. Do I understand you correctly?

Yes, see the edit.

Here are some steps for investigating and confirming your conjecture before proceeding further.

If I'm not mistaken, every term should be explicit when considering mixtures of Gaussians. Write down the appropriate formulas when one distribution is the standard Gaussian and the second a mixture of two Gaussians.

Check if you can have the mean of the mixture tend to infinity while your norm remains finite. If so, that should provide a counter-example.

If that fails to provide a counter-example, then my guess is that your conjecture is true.


